# directx11 can't add multiple objects

Tags: 3d, directx-11

Hi all I'm in a real bind, I am currently doing the directx11 tutorial Shapes example in 3d game programming with DirectX11 by Frank d Luna http://www.d3dcoder.net/d3d11.htm, I am currently trying to  add a second cube which I can place independently of the 1st cube, I create it and when I build the project both the cubes have now vanished I think the problem is with the geometry generator.

Please help :(

```
    void ShapesApp::BuildGeometryBuffers()
```

{
    GeometryGenerator::MeshData box;

```
//added
GeometryGenerator::MeshData boxtwo;


GeometryGenerator::MeshData grid;
GeometryGenerator::MeshData sphere;
GeometryGenerator::MeshData cylinder;

GeometryGenerator geoGen;

geoGen.CreateBox(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, box);

geoGen.CreateBox(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, boxtwo);
geoGen.CreateGrid(20.0f, 30.0f, 60, 40, grid);
geoGen.CreateSphere(0.5f, 20, 20, sphere);
//geoGen.CreateGeosphere(0.5f, 2, sphere);
geoGen.CreateCylinder(0.5f, 0.3f, 3.0f, 20, 20, cylinder);

// Cache the vertex offsets to each object in the concatenated vertex buffer.
//added


mBoxVertexOffset      = 0;
mBoxtwoVertexOffset = box.Vertices.size();
mGridVertexOffset     = mBoxtwoVertexOffset + boxtwo.Vertices.size();
mSphereVertexOffset   = mGridVertexOffset + grid.Vertices.size();
mCylinderVertexOffset = mSphereVertexOffset + sphere.Vertices.size();



// Cache the index count of each object.

mBoxIndexCount      = box.Indices.size();
//added
mBoxtwoIndexCount   = boxtwo.Indices.size();
mGridIndexCount     = grid.Indices.size();
mSphereIndexCount   = sphere.Indices.size();
mCylinderIndexCount = cylinder.Indices.size();


// Cache the starting index for each object in the concatenated index buffer.
mBoxIndexOffset      = 0;
//added
mBoxtwoIndexOffset      = mBoxIndexCount;
mGridIndexOffset     = mBoxtwoIndexOffset + mBoxtwoIndexCount;
mSphereIndexOffset   = mGridIndexOffset + mGridIndexCount;
mCylinderIndexOffset = mSphereIndexOffset + mSphereIndexCount;



UINT totalVertexCount = 

    box.Vertices.size() + 
    //added
    boxtwo.Vertices.size() + 
    grid.Vertices.size() + 
    sphere.Vertices.size() +
    cylinder.Vertices.size();

UINT totalIndexCount = 
    mBoxIndexCount + 
    //added
mBoxtwoIndexCount + 
    mGridIndexCount + 
    mSphereIndexCount +
    mCylinderIndexCount;
```

Comment: The title of your post says "directx11 can't multiple objects", I think you should correct it.

Comment: me thinks you are right, sorry :O

Answer (score 0):

You did the first part right it seems, but there is more to it.

- You then need to add the vertex positions for the second box
- Insert the indices for the second box in the Vector Index Buffer
- Add the code to draw the second box
- Create the second box world matrix to position it

I will suggest that you read the chapter again, it is very important that you understand each chapter completely and be able to modify its samples correctly before moving on, if not then you will run into a lot of problems in the chapters ahead.

Here is a patch with code changes that add a second box:

```
    --- D:/MyStuff/Book Files/Frank Luna/DVD/Code/Chapter 6 Drawing in Direct3D/Shapes/ShapesDemoOriginal.cpp   Mon May 09 22:10:02 2011
    +++ D:/MyStuff/Book Files/Frank Luna/DVD/Code/Chapter 6 Drawing in Direct3D/Shapes/ShapesDemo.cpp   Fri Jan 11 12:37:54 2013
    @@ -58,0 +59 @@
    +   XMFLOAT4X4 mBoxWorld2;
    @@ -65,0 +67 @@
    +   int mBoxVertexOffset2;
    @@ -70,0 +73 @@
    +   UINT mBoxIndexOffset2;
    @@ -75,0 +79 @@
    +   UINT mBoxIndexCount2;
    @@ -122,0 +127,4 @@
    +   XMMATRIX boxScale2 = XMMatrixScaling(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    +   XMMATRIX boxOffset2 = XMMatrixTranslation(2.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    +   XMStoreFloat4x4(&mBoxWorld2, XMMatrixMultiply(boxScale2, boxOffset2));
    +
    @@ -226,0 +235,6 @@
    +       
    +       // Draw the box2.
    +       world = XMLoadFloat4x4(&mBoxWorld2);
    +       mfxWorldViewProj->SetMatrix(reinterpret_cast<float*>(&(world*viewProj)));
    +       mTech->GetPassByIndex(p)->Apply(0, md3dImmediateContext);
    +       md3dImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(mBoxIndexCount2, mBoxIndexOffset2,         mBoxVertexOffset2);
    @@ -303,0 +318 @@
    +   GeometryGenerator::MeshData box2;
    @@ -309,0 +325 @@
    +   geoGen.CreateBox(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, box2);
    @@ -317 +333,2 @@
    -   mGridVertexOffset     = box.Vertices.size();
    +   mBoxVertexOffset2     = box.Vertices.size();
    +   mGridVertexOffset     = box.Vertices.size() + box2.Vertices.size();
    @@ -322,0 +340 @@
    +   mBoxIndexCount2     = box2.Indices.size();
    @@ -329 +347,2 @@
    -   mGridIndexOffset     = mBoxIndexCount;
    +   mBoxIndexOffset2     = mBoxIndexCount;
    +   mGridIndexOffset     = mBoxIndexOffset2 + mBoxIndexCount2;
    @@ -334,0 +354 @@
    +       box2.Vertices.size() + 
    @@ -340,0 +361 @@
    +       mBoxIndexCount2 + 
    @@ -360,0 +382,6 @@
    +   for(size_t i = 0; i < box2.Vertices.size(); ++i, ++k)
    +   {
    +       vertices[k].Pos   = box2.Vertices[i].Position;
    +       vertices[k].Color = black;
    +   }
    +
    @@ -394,0 +422 @@
    +   indices.insert(indices.end(), box2.Indices.begin(), box2.Indices.end());
```